# Getting error while adding entity in flutter project

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I had added multiple entities in object box and successfully build the build_runner.
`flutter pun run build_runner build`.
Now, I am adding two more entities but I am getting this error - *could not resolve annotation @Entity()*

Trying to add entities

```
import 'package:formula_application/objectbox.g.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'stop_test_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
  fieldRename: FieldRename.pascal,
)
@Entity()
class StopTest {
  StopTest(this.id, this.name);
  int id = 0;
  String name;
  //@Backlink()
  //final routes = ToMany<RouteTest>();

  factory StopTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$StopTestFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StopTestToJson(this);
}

\\separate route test file

import 'package:formula_application/objectbox.g.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'route_test_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
  fieldRename: FieldRename.pascal,
)
@Entity()
class RouteTest {
  RouteTest(this.id, this.name);
  int id = 0;
  String name;
  //final stops = ToMany<StopTest>();

  factory RouteTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$RouteTestFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RouteTestToJson(this);
}
```

After build_runner build command, I am getting this error

> [INFO] Generating build script... [INFO] Generating build script
> completed, took 514ms
>
> [INFO] Initializing inputs [INFO] Reading cached asset graph... [INFO]
> Reading cached asset graph completed, took 138ms
>
> [INFO] Checking for updates since last build... [INFO] Checking for
> updates since last build completed, took 926ms
>
> [INFO] Running build... [SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable
> on lib/models/test_model/route_test_model.dart:
>
> Null check operator used on a null value [SEVERE]
> json_serializable:json_serializable on
> lib/models/test_model/stop_test_model.dart:
>
> Null check operator used on a null value [SEVERE]
> objectbox_generator:resolver on
> lib/models/test_model/stop_test_model.dart:
>
> line 1, column 225 of
> package:formula_application/models/test_model/stop_test_model.dart:
> Could not resolve annotation for `class StopTest`.   ╷ 1 │ @Entity()
> │ ^^^^^^^^^   ╵ [WARNING] objectbox_generator:resolver on
> lib/models/test_model/route_test_model.dart: An unexpected error was
> thrown trying to get location information on `class RouteTest`
> (ClassElementImpl).
>
> Please file an issue at
> https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/new Include the
> contents of this warning and the stack trace along with the version of
> `package:source_gen`, `package:analyzer` from `pubspec.lock`.
>
> InconsistentAnalysisException: Requested result might be inconsistent
> with previously returned results
>
> [SEVERE] objectbox_generator:resolver on
> lib/models/test_model/route_test_model.dart:
>
> Could not resolve annotation for `class RouteTest`. [INFO] 4.2s
> elapsed, 4/6 actions completed. [INFO] Running build completed, took
> 4.5s
>
> [INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph... [INFO] Caching finalized
> dependency graph completed, took 66ms
>
> [SEVERE] Failed after 4.6s pub finished with exit code 1

I have tried to run the same without @JsonSerializable() annotation, using the plain class. Still getting same error.

Comment: Can you paste the whole file (including imports)?

Comment: It's rather weird though, especially since the error doesn't happen in objectbox-generator, rather in Dart's `source_gen` package. A minimal reproducible example could help to get you the answer.

Comment: @vaind thanks for pointing towards the error, while typing "@Entity()" the `objectbox.g.dart` file was automatically imported and I didn't check that. Now, when I was checking the imports, I changed the import from `objectbox.g.dart` to `'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart'` and build is working fine now

Comment: @raphire thanks for posting that solution. That was the same issue for me. Spent way too long trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

Change the

```
import 'package:formula_application/objectbox.g.dart';
```

to

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';
```